# Requirements for totally graph-reducing moves

Tags: graph-theory

This can be best explained with [Kuperbergs](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9201302) $G_2$ paper. Ingredients:

- (optional) Restrictions on the graph. $G_2$: only trivalent vertices, planar. (Crossing do come but only later...)
- Reducing moves. In knot theory, it's called "skein equation": you do some altering inside a circle and leave the outside unchanged. The original goes on the left hand side of the equation, the altered (can be more than a diagram - use linear combinations then) on the right, and it must somehow be "simpler" (for example, less vertices). $G_2$: all faces (closed loops) of size $1$ to $5$ are equated to open-chain sums.
- Totalness: A proof that this reduces *all* graphs. $G_2$: immediately obvious by Euler, since a planar graph can't consist only of $6$-loops and higher.
- Invariance: A proof that possible different moves "commute". $G_2$: just a bit of bookkeeping and determining coefficients.

Strangely, although skein equations are a very powerful concept of knot theory, I rarely saw them applied to graphs. For starters, it is straightforward to change "trivalent" to "tetravalent", $1-5$ to $1-3$ and get $B_2$ instead of $G_2$. (*I* did it.) Perhaps this was deemed unnecessary as a (much more elaborate) construction for a $B_2$ invariant was already given in the $G_2$ paper. And who has the complete overview over math literature of even a small field anyway...

Thus:

- Generally, can you point me to papers dealing with the "totalness" aspect of graph-reducing moves? (For example, in knot theory a long standing conjecture was that the Montesinos-Nakanishi 3-move alteration was total - until [Przytycki et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205040) busted it. But I'm more interested in planar graphs at the moment.)
- I'm not sure if the construction of the Tutte polynomial $T$ falls under the skein requirements - if yes, the $G_2$ invariant would be a special case of it since $T$ is "most general" in some sense, and I never read that assertion! But still - is deletion/contraction a skein (analog) move, and if not, why?
- Specifically, my intution says that for a planar graph with only tetravalent vertices, reducing $1-$ and $2-$loops and merely rotating a $3-$loop is sufficient. Is it? (A $3-$loop could "swim" through a "sea" of $4-$loops until it "annihilates" with another $3-$loop. I could swear I even saw a proof somewhere, but can't find it anymore.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the definition of "reducing"?

Comment: @AndrewUzzell: Any move(s) that can only be applied a finite number of times since the graph is empty then. The most obvious is an equation with one graph on the left side, and all graphs on the right have one face less (the G2 paper). One vertex less would work either. Consider my very last paragraph: Assume my babbling is true. You could move the 3-loops anywhere. Move three around to meet at a vertex, a special move then exists killing this vertex.